# Geodesic distance on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Recently I came across this old [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267430/measuring-distance-in-son) or [this paper (w.o. proof)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0895479801383877) discussing the geodesic distance on $\SO(n)$ when it is equipped with the left-invariant Riemannian metric given by $g_{I_n}(X,Y):=-\operatorname{tr}(XY)$ for $X,Y\in T_{I_n}\SO(n)\leftrightarrow \mathfrak{so}(n)$.  The post states that, the *length/geodesic metric* induced by $g$ is
$$
d(A,B)^2:= \sum_{i=1}^d \theta_i^2
$$
where $\theta_i=\ln(\lambda_{i}(A^{\top}B))$, for any $A,B\in \SO(n)$, where $\{\lambda_{i}(A^{\top}B)\}_{i=1}^d$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{\top}B$.  Where can I find a proof, or a reference, to this fact?

Comment: Do you want _i to be a number or a matrix?

Comment: @DanielAsimov Sorry, $\theta_i$ is the log of the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of $A^{\top}B$.

Comment: Geometrically, every element M ∈ SO(n) has a decomposition of R^n into orthogonal 2-planes P_1, ..., P_k each taken to themselves by M, where k = floor(n/2) (and for n odd, one additional orthogonal line that is fixed). On each P_j, g acts as rotation by some angle _j. So a bi-invariant metric on SO(n) is given by d(A,B) = √∑(_j)^2 if the _j ∈ [0, π] are the corresponding rotation angles.

Comment: Since your ln(_j) will be imaginary, you probably want the _j defined to be the absolute value |ln(_j )|, and restricted to the interval [0, π].

Comment: @DanielAsimov That makes sense, intuitively.  Though do you know where I could find a reference?

Comment: I just found this by googling: https://planetmath.org/decompositionoforthogonaloperatorsasrotationsandreflections .

Comment: And where I wrote "corresponding rotation angles" I meant "of the matrix A^T B".

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for a book or paper I can cite (now that your explanation really helped :) )

Comment: Just saw a notice to "avoid extended discussions in comments". My reply is: Please avoid interfering with useful discussions.

Comment: Ahaha, yes I agree with this.  Funny though, a citation of this fact seems to be extremely illusive.

Comment: @DanielAsimov Thinking about this problem and doing some reading, I noticed the following: the distance on the space of symmetric positive definite matrices with the same Riemannian metric has the same distance function expression.  Is this a coincidence or is there a deeper thing going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula holds with a minus sign on the RHS and only for small enough distances. Here's a short proof: by invariance you may set $A = I_n$. Then for $B$ close enough to $I_n$, the unit-speed minimising geodesic from $I_n$ to $B$ is a one-parameter subgroup $\gamma(s) = \exp(s \Xi)$, for some $\Xi \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$ with ${\rm tr}\, \Xi^2 = -1$. We thus have $B = \exp(d \Xi)$, where $d = d(I_n, B)$, and the eigenvalues satisfy $\theta_i = \ln \lambda_i = d \xi_i$, where $\xi_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\Xi$. Your formula follows since $\sum \xi_i^2 = -1$. (Notice the minus sign on the RHS.)

Comment: Let me also add that "small enough" means in a ball of radius $R$ where $\pi/\sqrt{2} \le R\le \pi \sqrt{2 \lfloor n/2\rfloor} $; where $R$ is the injectivity radius on $(SO(n),g)$ and $g$ is the aforementioned bi-invariant metric.

Comment: @ABIM Because the injectivity radius on $<\operatorname{SO}(n),g)$ is at-least $\pi/\sqrt{2}$?